# Call typescript decorator method when the underlying function is executed

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

As per how typescript design works ,if i write a decorator like,

```
class foo{

   @fooDecorator
   public fooMethod(){

    }
}
```

it gives the transpiled javascript as

```
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
 };
var foo = (function () {
function foo() {
}
foo.prototype.fooMethod = function () {
};
__decorate([
    fooDecorator
], foo.prototype, "fooMethod", null);
return foo;
}());
```

as per there transpiled code whenever my app gets bootstrapped the decorator function get executed, but how i want is whenever the underlying function "fooMethod" is executed the decorator method "fooDecorator" should execute, how can i attain the same, please help me with the issue

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it like this. In the decorator replace your original method with 'wrapper' that will first call the supplied method that should be called each time and then call the original one.

The code below illustrate this approach:

Your decorator:

```
export function Foo(funcToCallEveryTime: (...args: any[]) => void)
{
    return (target: any, key: string, descriptor: any) => 
    {
        var originalMethod = descriptor.value; 

        descriptor.value =  function (...args: any[]) {
            funcToCallEveryTime(...args);
            return originalMethod.apply(target, args);
        }

        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

And method you decorate with @Foo decorator like this:

```
@Foo((...args: any[]) => { console.log("Before method call:", args[0]); })
private TestMethod(param: string): void
{
    console.log("Method call");
    //...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thnx for the reply, but i dnt want to pass any argument to decorator

Comment: you can allways hardcode that function inside decorator inself and apply decorator like `@Foo()`. But it will not be as flexible.

Comment: but according to the transpiled javascript foo will get executed as soon the app gets bootstrapped ??

Comment: @Foo() - yes. But not the funcToCallEveryTime handler. That we setup to be called each time before actual method call

Comment: seems to be working but, it seems that the descirptor.value is replacing the original function to the one which is defined in the decorator but since i am managing the object creation and hence i cannot pass the "this" param, is there any alternative to call the original function after the descriptor function is being called

Comment: The sample I gave calls first added function then original.

Comment: But you can't pass TestMethod into `@Foo` and have the decorator execute after the TestMethod?

Comment: @lolelo you can, but you just have to switch the `funcToCallEveryTime` and the `originalMethod.apply`